# Saml with SpringBoot and Azure - how can I have application state?

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I have implemented Saml authentication with Springboot using Azure as Identity Provider.
this SpringBoot application is called by another application for doing the SSO process.
I would like to be able to get back to the original URL I ccame from. How can I do it? How can I send Azure some state/URL which I could read from the controller?

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration
{

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {

        OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setResponseAuthenticationConverter(groupsConverter());

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .saml2Login(saml2 -> saml2
                        .authenticationManager(new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider)))
                .saml2Logout(withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    private Converter<OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.ResponseToken, Saml2Authentication> groupsConverter()
    {

        Converter<ResponseToken, Saml2Authentication> delegate =
                OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.createDefaultResponseAuthenticationConverter();

        return (responseToken) -> {
            Saml2Authentication authentication = delegate.convert(responseToken);
            Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal = (Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
            List<String> groups = principal.getAttribute("groups");
            Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
            if (groups != null) {
                groups.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).forEach(authorities::add);
            } else {
                authorities.addAll(authentication.getAuthorities());
            }
            return new Saml2Authentication(principal, authentication.getSaml2Response(), authorities);
        };
    }
}



@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(@AuthenticationPrincipal Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", principal.getName());
        model.addAttribute("emailAddress", principal.getFirstAttribute("email"));
        model.addAttribute("userAttributes", principal.getAttributes());
        return "home";
    }

}
```